# How to not print the lines that have more than a certain number of characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to print the lines that have numbers that are either greater or equal to 3 and less than or equal to 6. The problem is that the regular expression I have prints out the files that are 3 or more and not 3 to 6.

**What I am trying to get**

Valid:

123

34564

234552

Invalid:

12

1453756

**What I am getting**

Valid:

123

34564

234552

1453756

Invalid:

12

```
 /[0-9]{3,6}/
```

Comment: because I want no more than 6 numbers but no less than 3

Comment: ok then did you try: `/^[0-9]{3,6}$/` ?

Comment: look for the trailing spaces..they may be cause of your problem..also you need to include anchors because a number of 6 length is sub string of 7 length..so it matches

Comment: Are you using BRE or ERE? For BRE, you need to escape the `{` and `}`: `/^[0-9]\{3,6\}/`. Else, `/^[0-9]{3,6}$/` should really work.

Comment: Any news? Which one is working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, and it worked for me :
`\d{3,6}`

Comment: gives me the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following

```
^[\d]{3,6}[^\d]
```

It is working as specified in your requirement